# Edit SVG xml text content after converted from PDF

Tags: java, xml, svg, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to Convert my PDF to SVG file and I would like to change the text content using the xml format in SVG. However, the changed text font seem to be very different and the alignment is totally off from the original place.

Hence, how can I edit the text content using SVG? is there any other tool can be done by converting the PDF to SVG and edit the text content?

Comment: If you would like help with your SVG, then please post a sample. It's hard to give advice on imaginary SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in the 2 formats that can cause issues when converting from pdf to svg, take a read over [this guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Graphics_Lab/Resources/PDF_conversion_to_SVG#Conversion_with_Inkscape). It's suggested to try [pdf2svg](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/)  if you don't mind getting your hands dirty.

Excerpt below:

Conversion with Inkscape

1. Download Inkscape from www.inkscape.org (version 0.46 and above)
2. Download the PDF you want to convert
3. Run Inkscape
4. Open the PDF file you want convert in Inkscape (not Acrobat)
5. Uncheck Embed images on the box that comes up and click OK
6. Wait a little while as Inkscape converts it
7. Click File>Save As..
8. Under Save as type:, choose "Plain SVG (*.svg)"
9. Click Save in the bottom right corner
10. Done! You now have an SVG file with the same name as the PDF, but with the .svg extension
11. Before uploading you may assure its W3C-validity, with tool SVG-check
12. For checking that it displays properly, upload it first to Test.svg
13. Upload the SVG to Wikimedia Commons and tag it with {{Extracted with Inkscape|v}}

Conversion with PDF2SVG

1. Some versions of Inkscape do not have PDF support compiled in; also, text importing does not always produce satisfactory results in Inkscape. In that case, you might try performing the conversion with the PDF2SVG command line tool. (It requires that Poppler, Cairo, and X are installed on your system.)
2. Get PDF2SVG from http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/ and compile it. If you are using Linux or FreeBSD or MacPorts, PDF2SVG might also be installable via the package installer.
3. Convert the PDF with pdf2svg file.pdf file.svg
   If necessary use Inkscape to edit the resulting SVG.